# How to get the parent controller in controller as Syntax in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular bootstrap modal like this

```
   var myModal = $modal.open({
        controller: 'MyUpdateController as muc',
        templateUrl: 'views/create_form.html',
```

Now my parent controller is `ParentController as PC`.

I want to know how can I access `PC` inside `muc` or inside `create_form` template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access controller alias from respective scope or its descendants carried down via inheritance (Alias is attached on the scope as a property name with the value holding the reference of controller instance). angular ui modal takes a scope property which you can use to set your modal to a specific scope (it is otherwise defaulted to rootScope). So set the scope property in your modal

```
 $modal.open({
    controller: 'MyUpdateController as muc',
    templateUrl: 'views/create_form.html',
    //Create a child scope of current scope or even pass the current $scope itself but be aware
    scope:$scope.$new()
```

Inject `$scope` in your controller (`MyUpdateController`) and access parent scope as `$scope.PC` and you can access this alias in you template as well.

Another way you can probably use `resolve` property of the modal and pass the current parent scope to it.

```
$modal.open({
    controller: 'MyUpdateController as muc',
    templateUrl: 'views/create_form.html',
    resolve: {
       parentCtrl: function(){
         return ctrl; //return controller here
       }
    }
```

and inject `parentCtrl` as dependency in your `MyUpdateController` and get it and set it on the scope.

Comment: thanks for that , but i didn't get `return ctrl` what will be `ctrl` here

Comment: @user3214546 It can just be your controller (whch i assume can access PC or it is PC). I just used a variable thats it, because you cannot pass `this` there, you would need to have it cached outside. So more like in your current controller you do `var vm=this;` inorder to avoid the `this` context access issue right (unless using typescript)?, ctrl is vm in that case.

Comment: so u mean , if i have `vm = this` then i can `return vm` . is that right

Comment: yes, right. You got it. And then get it on your modal controller and set it on its scope as a value of some property, say `PC` and access it in the templaye

Comment: thanks one thing more. suppose i want to use same controller `PC` in modal and i don't want new MyUpdate controller , how can i then access `PC` inside template because then i have to remove controller line from it

Comment: `scope:scope` or even `scope:scope.$new()` it should work, try it out

Comment: thanks ,  that worked , i had to use `scope: $scope`